# Classic ASP, MSSQL can't display gb2312

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

hope you are all doing well.

So to the question, we have an asp website, (asp classic 2.0) with MSSQL server 2008, IIS7 in "a" server. We moved the whole website to another server that has exact environment, but we have a problem.

The data inside the DB is properly in chinese character. But when I want to display the data onto the website, it shows weird characters.

As for my code, I have put

```
response.charset = "gb2312"
```

and at the very top after html tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
```

But still it shows weird characters.

On its former server, it served well.

The only part that is not displaying correctly is the data from the DB. While the hand coded characters display correctly.

Is there anything I need to add/set?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find the codepage value for your character set.  Eg, if you were using utf-8 you would begin your pages with

```
<%@language="VBScript" codepage="65001"%>
```

If you can, you're better off using utf-8 than a language specific set, but if your database is full of gb2312 encoded copy then I can understand why you wouldn't want to change it.

This blog post contains a lot of useful info

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx